# PHP - How to determine whether there is an entry in the field

Tags: php

How to determine whether there is an entry in the field? My efforts not work :-(
Advise anyone? Thank you.

```
$array = array(
  array('id' => '0','key' => 'aaa','ttl' => 'AAA'),
  array('id' => '1','key' => 'bbb','ttl' => 'BBB'),
  array('id' => '2','key' => 'ccc','ttl' => 'CCC'),
  array('id' => '3','key' => 'ddd','ttl' => 'DDD'),
  array('id' => '4','key' => 'eee','ttl' => 'EEE'),
  array('id' => '5','key' => 'fff','ttl' => 'FFF'),
  array('id' => '6','key' => 'ggg','ttl' => 'GGG'),
  array('id' => '7','key' => 'hhh','ttl' => 'HHH'),
);

$var = 'fff';

if(array_search($var, $array)){
     echo 'Exists';
}else{
     echo 'No Exists';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a multidimensional array, so `array_search()` won't just work like this. But you can combine it with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) like this:

(Also note that I check that it's not FALSE, because your condition would fail if the key is 0)

```
$var = 'fff';

if(array_search($var, array_column($array, "ttl")) !== FALSE){
     echo 'Exists';
}else{
     echo 'No Exists';
}
```

<sub>FYI: `array_search()` is case sensitive, so for case insensitivity just wrap `strtoupper()` around your `$var`in the `array_search()`</sub>

**(extra) EDIT:**

For people with PHP <5.5:

```
foreach($array as $v) {
    if(array_search(strtoupper($var), $v)) {
        echo "Exists";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @VolkerAndres Since we are in 2015 I hope and assume that every one has a PHP version of 5.5 or higher

Comment: Lets hope it ;) If not, there are a lot of possible implementations in the comments of the official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: @ Izier123: Hi, thank you. I tried your code ...  Fatal error: Call to undefined function core\array_column() in ... My PHP Version 5.4.36-0+deb7u3

Comment: @IngDedek updated the answer with a method which should work for you